# How to Merge datas while plotting graphs

Tags: core-data, xcode4.5

Can anyone tell how to merge two files in xcode as i have created two datas for "line graph" and "bar graph" and now i need to present a view with both the datas on same graph ?

***How to merge a Bar Graph and Line Graph in  XCode ? Without core plot ?***

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just plot your two "datas" on the graph. If your graph uses an array to hold its data, append the second set of data to the first.

```
finalDataArray = [firstDataArray 
                      arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:secondDataArray];
```